# Android Hybrid Application and Remote Server Communication

Tags: android, http, client-server, hybrid

I am learning to develop Hybrid Application for Android platform (which will be extended to other mobile platforms later). I have read a number of articles and have got a start but have not come across something which explains this.

I want to store the UI (HTML/JavaScript/CSS) files on the mobile device and display it via the WebView. This will communicate with a remote server to fetch data via a WebService.
What I have not understood specifically is:

1. Will the UI files (HTML/JavaScript/CSS) be installed on the file
   system of android device or will there be a local embedded WebServer
   on the android device.
2. If the HTML/JavaScript/CSS files are on the file system how do they
   communicate with the remote WebService.  Let’s say I want to make an
   AJAX call to the remote server…  will it be handled by UI
   (HTML/JavaScript) files displayed via WebView or by the JAVA
   Container in which the WebView is sitting in? What I did not
   understand is how can an HTML/JavaScript sitting on the file system
   make AJAX calls.
3. If a local embedded WebServer is required on mobile device can you
   suggest me some? And if this is true will the same architecture work
   on others platforms as well like iOS, Symbian, BlackBerry etc.

If anyone feels this is not the right way to go please let me know your thoughts on the architecture.

Kindly point me to the right articles or explain your thought on this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go with a different approach for these problem. Had I been in your place I would have done the following:

I am assuming that you are making these as a java based web application. Even of you go for PHP or other web development language things will reamin pretty much the same.

**1)Will the UI files (HTML/JavaScript/CSS) be installed on the file system of android device or will there be a local embedded WebServer on the android device.**

No. The UI files that you are toking about are nothing but web pages in your web application. these web pages are stored on the server not on your local file system. We make use of browser to connect to the remote server these pages are then fetched from their by your browser processed and then displayed to you.

**2)If the HTML/JavaScript/CSS files are on the file system how do they communicate with the remote WebService. Let’s say I want to make an AJAX call to the remote server… will it be handled by UI (HTML/JavaScript) files displayed via WebView or by the JAVA Container in which the WebView is sitting in? What I did not understand is how can an HTML/JavaScript sitting on the file system make AJAX calls.**

Web page is downloaded from server and displayed to you in your browser. In the web page itself we write scripts to make AJAX calls on appropriate events like on click of some button, or change in value of some field or @ the time of page load etc. When you want to make a AJAX call is all dependent on your project requirement.

**3)If a local embedded WebServer is required on mobile device can you suggest me some? And if this is true will the same architecture work on others platforms as well like iOS, Symbian, BlackBerry etc.**

Now as I have mentioned earlier that the data is stored on the remote server so you dont need a web server on your mobile device (unless you want to use your mobile device as the hosting or server device). As these is a web based solution you dont have to think about the platform of your mobile phone. Be it a android, blackberry, Apple or a symbian phone all you do is connect to the server with the web browser that is their in your phone.

Comment: Thanks @svg. This question was unanswered for a long time.